# Is it a good practice to define TRUE/FALSE constants in SystemVerilog?

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

Is it a good practice to define TRUE, FALSE, HIGH, LOW, ENABLE and DISABLE constants/defines/parameters in separate file and use them in expression `some_reg <= FALSE;` instead of  `some_reg <= 0;` ?

Does this practice have any negative effects?

Comment: Not that I know of. Except that the file size increases. It improves coding readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good practice is creating a `package` with a set of global parameters used by your project that you can import. Putting them in a package avoids namespace collisions with other projects or external IP that you might have to integrate later.

`` `define `` macros are global and have the problem with namespace collisions and file compilation order dependancies.

`const` *variables* are not *constants*, they are still ***variables***. See [Verilog - Use integer constant to define signal width](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/555014/verilog-use-integer-constant-to-define-signal-width/555017?noredirect=1#comment1447456_555017)

Answer (score 3):

The downside is that you obviously are adding more terms to the namespace (although these are probably names you would treat as reserved, just by habit). There's also the issue of active low signals, so you might need an `nENABLE` for example. Up to you though, wouldn't say it's best/worst practice. If you think it improves maintainability or readability then it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't overthink or overcomplicate. If you feel it helps you, do it.

As an example of what shouldn't be done, I once saw a project with a lot of components, each with a single line of code and obviously about two dozens of lines of overhead. So if you don't go there, it might make sense to have True/False constants, as well as msec, usec, etc.

As mentioned before, use a package to have same names in your project. Actually, it could be a company-wide and even carer-spanning package.